# CakePHP one of the validation rules is not applied during edit/update

Tags: cakephp

Here are the 3 validation rule that are applied for "initials" field:

```
'initials' => array(
    'Not empty' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'message'=>'Please enter a customer\'s initials'
    ),
    'Unique' => array(
        'rule' => array('isUniqueForCompany'),
        'message' => 'Customer with these initials already exists'
    ),
    'Long' => array(
        'rule' => array('between', 2, 12),
        'message' => 'Initials should be between 2 and 12 characters long'
    )
)
```

When creating a new record, all 3 rules are applied, but when updating/editting the 'Unique' rule is skipped out.

What can cause such a problem? 
If needed, I can provide the controller actions ar view forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you have a problem with your custom `isUniqueForCompany` validation function in the model.

It's probably returning true when it shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thats all that I needed, missed out the return false in once case. Time to take a break